# Water cooler faucet handle broke

Tags: water, faucet

After a decade of use, it looks like my water cooler is slowly falling apart.
I am not sure of the proper terminology here, but the handle/lever part of the faucet broke off.

- Am I able to buy just the handle and install it (not the entire faucet)
- If I have to install the entire faucet, is there a guide/manual somewhere? I couldn't scavenge anything relevant.
- Is there a temporary workaround that I could do to still use the faucet?

Image of the damage (blue, center):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've not found an image to match the handles in the photo. Without a model designation, it's challenging to zero in on the same product, but the images I've found indicate there are similarities in your product and the parts available.

My search terms were "sunbeam water cooler handles" and could be modified by adding your model number for best results. I was surprised to see that WalMart carries replacement parts, but that's likely to be online and not necessarily available in stores. Amazon also popped up in the search results.

[image: water cooler handles]

It appears that you may be able to dismantle the nozzle just above the opening if parts are available for that segment, or you should be able to remove the entire assembly for replacement as well.